# Is it possible to create a button activated macro to peform an accumulative sum in one cell then loop on itself everytime I press the button

Tags: excel, vba, button

I'm currently trying to create a yearly total that gets added on to every time i hit a button the problem is the code is trying to loop on itself.

`AA5 = AA5+Z5`

i also need the code to affect both Z and AA columns from Z5 and AA5 downwards.

```
Week 1 Z5 "200" AA5 "200"
week 2 Z5 "350" AA5 "550"
Week 3 Z5 "620" AA5 "1170"
```

just so every time i make a payment the total goes up but i don't wish to have a giant list of every week and what payment just the current week and the total paid all together.
This is the macro i tried to record but failed.

```
`Sub Accumulate()
    Range("AA5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC+RC[-1]"
    Range("AA5").Select
End Sub`
```

I was wondering if it was possible or if i had to make two separate macros where the first would  do the total in a third spot then say AB5 then the second macro will make `AA5 = AB5` then manually preform both loops too separate buttons.

[image]

Comment: does it need to be VBA? You can do that with a formula just copying it down. Your question is a bit unclear. Can you provide proper example data and the result that you expect? It is pretty unclear how your data actually looks like.

Comment: It doesn't need to be a VBA i just thought it would be more convenient.
So I'm creating a payroll for my fathers company. I want to get total of money received in the financial year every week. so i just need it to accumulate every week but to accumulate it needs to add the total earnings plus this weeks earnings. the problem is I can't seem to figure a way to automate it because it just creates a loop on it's se;f and fails as a function. I don't have to manually add them up and change it each week.

Comment: Can you give some proper example data (or screenshot, you can hide sensitive data) and tell what exactly you want to sum and by which criteria? • Also you might want to have a look at the formula functions `SUMIF` and `SUMIFS` which can sum by one or more criteria.

Comment: I still don't get which numbers in your pictures should get calculated (summed) and which would be the result? Can you please explain the calculation that you plan to do on your picture step by step? Also explain what you mean by Week 1 … 3 which I cannot find in your screenshot.